# How to enable multiprocessor compilation in call to msbuild but not in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

There are a number of teams in our company who use a subset of common libraries. Some projects are able to use different build scripts, and so in one project we'd like to be able to build with `msbuild` using the `/m` option to build projects in parallel (some other projects use `devenv` to build). This option can be set in a build script so the projects don't need to change.

The question is how we can also apply the `/MP` option to `cl.exe` to allow multiprocessor builds inside each project, but without changing the common libraries.  Inside Visual Studio you can apply a user property sheet, which won't change the project files, but is there a way of doing the same thing for `msbuild` by providing an argument or property sheet that can apply custom build settings without changing the projects?

EDIT:

Maybe a simpler way of summarising the question is: can I add custom arguments to the `cl.exe` process when calling `msbuild`?

Comment: It is very unclear why you are having a problem with this.  The IDE also uses msbuild.exe, running it yourself from the command line doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It has been my understanding, from previous Microsoft conferences, that building from the command line with `devenv` has been deprecated in favour of doing it via `msbuild`. In any case, even if I used `devenv`, I would still need a way of passing a custom property sheet to it

Comment: What does this custom property sheet do that you can't or don't want do in the project file?  Please be specific.

Comment: I want to apply the `/MP` setting to all projects in the solution *without* changing those projects. This can be done in a user property sheet, but that requires a file added in %APPDATA%. If you add a custom property sheet to the project then you change the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer: properties can be passed to the MSBuild [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z7f65y0d.aspx). This can specify any of the properties for the [CL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee862477%28v=vs.100%29.aspx/css), so msbuild can be invoked with:

```
msbuild file.sln /property:MultiProcessorCompilation=true
```

There's also a useful article on tuning VS2010 parallel build performance here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/03/08/tuning-c-build-parallelism-in-vs2010.aspx

Comment: /p:MultiProcessorCompilation=false does not seem to work.

Comment: @Trass3r Yes, seems only the enabling is supported. So I've successfully used `/p:CL_MPCount=1` instead (see [KalenGi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722917/4763489)).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to set environment variable 
CL=/MP
?

Comment: Good suggestion - I've just found the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kezkeayy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Following the description here https://github.com/Microsoft/checkedc-clang/wiki/Parallel-builds-of-clang-on-Windows, I was able to call MSBuild like so

```
MSBuild /m:2 /p:CL_MPCount=2 /p:Configuration=Release tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj
```

This allowed a maximum of 2 parallel projects (MSBuild) with 2 compilations (Cl) each.